# Python3 - write back to same stream in yaml

Tags: python, yaml

**Goal**: There is a yaml file with multiple streams. I want to append a key/value to a single stream. Then write the addition, including the original other streams, back into the file.

Example:

file.yaml contains:

```
---
one_key: value
---
kind: Deployment
appendhere:
  subkey: subvaluekey
---
third_key: value
```

Now, run the python script should run with this as desired output:

```
---
one_key: value
---
kind: Deployment
appendhere:
  subkey: subvaluekey
  alright: value
---
third_key: value
```

**My code**: I can append the subkey to the stream.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import yaml

stream = open('file.yaml', 'r')
for data in yaml.load_all(stream, Loader=yaml.FullLoader):
  for k, v in data.items():
    if "kind" in k:
      if "Deployment" in v:
          data['appendhere'].update({'addedkey': {'alright', 'value'}})
```

I don’t know how to program Python to write back into file.yaml ; by keeping the other original streams, and the stream I appended a key to.

Comment: Where does your code go wrong?

Comment: I don’t know how to write back into file.yaml ; by keeping the other original streams, and the stream I appended a key to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store the read list of documents somewhere so that you can dump it again:

```py
with open('file.yaml', 'r+') as stream:
  documents = list(yaml.load_all(stream, Loader=yaml.FullLoader))
  for data in documents:
    # [snip] modification code
  # move position in stream to front
  stream.seek(0)
  yaml.dump_all(documents, stream)
  # discards surplus content when new data is smaller than old data
  stream.truncate()
```

Comment: Can you verify this yourself? I tried your code, but I'm not receiving the desired output, not even close :/
https://pastebin.com/PuLmc3zS , the file is empty..

Comment: Ah sorry, forgot that since `yaml.load_all` returns a generator, we need to explicitly construct a list. Fixed the code.