# "a"/"append" only once to yaml file

Tags: python, pandas, pyyaml

I'm trying to use yaml.dump to send some data from an .csv file to .yml file!
Everything works and I can send data successfully BUT the script is meant to be run many times... And this adds the same data to the .yml file every time i run the script.

My code in python:

```
# Reading whole csv file with panda library.
df = pandas.read_csv('Keywords.csv', sep=';')

for index, row in df.iterrows(): # Iterates the csv file.

    pack_name = row.NAME # Name of the pack
    print(pack_name)

    def dumpFunction():
        with open(f'packs/{pack_name}/config.yml', 'a') as outfile: # HERE I USE APPEND
            yaml.dump_all(
            df.loc[(df['NAME'] == pack_name)].to_dict(orient='records'), # Send keywords to the right pack.
            outfile,
            sort_keys=False,
            indent=4
            )

    if pack_name and os.path.exists(f'packs/{pack_name}'): # Check if the pack is available, row.NAME is the pack name.
        dumpFunction()
    else:
        pathlib.Path(f"packs/{pack_name}").mkdir() # If pack not exist I will make one new
        dumpFunction()
        print(f'{pack_name} was made!')
```

My .csv file (shortened) - semicolon separated:

```
NAME;KEYWORDS
.NET;apm, .net, language agent
.NET core;apm, .net
.NET MVC Web API;apm, .net
ActiveRecord;apm, ruby
Acts_as_solr;apm, ruby
```

My .yml file after I run script 3 times:

```
NAME: .NET
KEYWORDS: apm, .net, language agent
NAME: .NET
KEYWORDS: apm, .net, language agent
NAME: .NET
KEYWORDS: apm, .net, language agent
```

I only want it once like this in .yml file even if I run the script 10 times:

```
NAME: .NET
KEYWORDS: apm, .net, language agent
```

Comment: Without knowledge of the structure of the input CSV file, it's rather hard to make any sense of this. Could you please [edit] to clarify what the input looks like and how it's supposed to work?

Comment: I added .csv file and changed .yml file now. @tripleee

Comment: Simply replace the file instead of append to it.

Comment: If the file is not that huge, I suggest you 
1. read the file to a file to an object
2. then truncate the file 
3. update the object with the new update you have
4. rewrite the file and save

Comment: The file is big, 400 rows @Enkum

Comment: How do you mean? Can you give me an code example? I'm 2 days into Python @tripleee

Comment: @gospecomid12 400 rows!? not that big. I think the approach I mentioned above can help you out. Truncating the file has a better chance of assuring the data you have to be complete as well. Check it and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:
I didn't have enough data in the CSV to test it but it should work.

I have referenced this answer [Python3 - write back to same stream in yaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60995595/python3-write-back-to-same-stream-in-yaml)

```
import os
import pathlib
import pandas
import yaml

df = pandas.read_csv('Keywords.csv', sep=';')

for index, row in df.iterrows(): # Iterates the csv file.

    pack_name = row.NAME # Name of the pack
    print(pack_name)

    def dumpFunction():
        with open(f'packs/{pack_name}/config.yml', 'w+') as outfile: # HERE I USE APPEND
            f = outfile.read()
            old_yaml_content = yaml.load_all(outfile, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
            
            outfile.seek(0)
            
            yaml.dump_all(
            df.loc[(df['NAME'] == pack_name)].to_dict(orient='records'), # Send keywords to the right pack.
            outfile,
            sort_keys=False,
            indent=4
            )
            outfile.truncate()

    if pack_name and os.path.exists(f'packs/{pack_name}'): # Check if the pack is available, row.NAME is the pack name.
        dumpFunction()
    else:
        pathlib.Path(f"packs/{pack_name}").mkdir() # If pack not exist I will make one new
        dumpFunction()
        print(f'{pack_name} was made!')
```